# How can I extract some frames of a rtsp using directly python or python-opencv?

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ffmpeg

I want to know if there is any method of Python or probably from python-opencv that allows me to extract frames from a rtsp streaming. I know that such task can be done easily using a ffmpeg library but ffmpeg uses a lot of my CPU.

Comment: You can try to use PyAv https://mikeboers.github.io/PyAV/ it's a ffmpeg libav binding.

Comment: You can just use OpenCV: `cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://link_to_stream")`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RTSP stream and OpenCV (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891936/rtsp-stream-and-opencv-python)