# OpenCV RTSP capture is not opening

Tags: python, opencv, rtsp, onvif

I trying create capture RTSP stream  by my ip camera. It is good working in VLC player, but not work in python 3.6 with OpenCV package.

I run this code:

```
import cv2
sUrl = 'rtsp://admin:*****@**.***.***.***:554/onvif1'
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(sUrl)

while(1):
    ret, frame = vcap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

and get this error:

> error
>   Traceback (most recent call last) 
>    in ()
>         8 while(1):
>         9     ret, frame = vcap.read()
>   ---> 10     cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
>        11     cv2.waitKey(1)
>
> error: OpenCV(3.4.1)
>   C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1533128839831\work\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:356:
>   error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow

after, I check capture

```
vcap.isOpened()
```

### and I get `False` value

Python version -  3.6
OS - Windows 10
OpenCV version -  2.4.12

Thank you!

Comment: are you sure is a rtsp stream? sounds more like onvif ? which model of camera you have?

Comment: This is realy onvif. Maybe I not quite understand why working onvif. It seemed to me that onvif simply protocol of protection... ESCAM Button Q6

Comment: onvif is more than just a stream, you can control the camera (move it) and do even more things. rtsp is just a stream. Try with something like: `rtsp:// ip:port/user=admin_password=pass_channel=1_stream=0.sdp` or `rtsp://admin:pass@ip:port/11`

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not work. I running this in CLV and in my script. Maybe, perhaps use packeges for onvif?

Comment: try to use this link to test your app : rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov . If it doesn't open, the problem is with your opencv app. Else, the problem is with you onvif rtsp link. You can also test your onvif rtsp link with the VLC media player.

Comment: @LoukMo I checked my stream in VLC - it's worked. And Your stream capturing in my code with out problem. It turns out, the problem is in my stream..

Comment: try to turn off your firewall.. maybe this will help! (:

Comment: If I understand correctly, when you open the big buck bunny rtsp link in your app, it does work. But when you try to open YOUR rtsp link, it doesn't... The problem is with the link you give. To know what is the good rtsp link to your stream, use the [ONVIF Device Manager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifdm/) and look in the streaming part... you'll find the good rtsp link to the stream of your camera. TLDR: You don't have the good rtsp link. Find the good one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RTSP stream and OpenCV (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891936/rtsp-stream-and-opencv-python)