# Distorted frame when using rtsp stream from IP with opencv camera in python

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, opencv, python

I am getting rtsp stream from IP camera and then passing the stream in opencv for getting frame, but i am getting distorted frame in that.
But when i am using video file instead of rtsp stream frame is not distorted.

```py
import cv2
 video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://ip_address/onvif1")
 while True:
   ret, frame = video_capture.read()
   cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
```

When streaming directly in vlc player and in ffmpeg frame is not distorting.

[image: This output i am getting when streaming through rtsp using ip camera in opencv]

Answer (score 0):

**Credit from : [RTSP stream and OpenCV (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891936/rtsp-stream-and-opencv-python)**

You might need to put opencv_ffmpeg.dll in your working directory.
Then edit your code like this:

```
 video_capture = cv.VideoCapture("rtsp://ip_address/onvif1/out.h264") 
    while(1):
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    cv.imshow('VIDEO', frame)
    cv.waitKey(1)
```