# FFMPEG RTSP Stream timeout triggered after 30015.187000 ms

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ffmpeg, rtsp

I am trying to read several RTSP streams using opencv cv2.VideoCapture(URL). It has FFMPEG backend. Sometimes for few streams it is throwing timeout warning after 30 seconds.

```
[ WARN:0@123.394] global cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:453 _opencv_ffmpeg_interrupt_callback Stream timeout triggered after 30015.187000 ms
```

I tried setting up the timeout flag.

```
import os
os.environ["OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS"] = "timeout;5000" # 5 seconds 
cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://URL", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
```

Ref: [How to terminate cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp_url) call if execution stalls due to RTSP camera issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68628450/how-to-terminate-cv2-videocapturertsp-url-call-if-execution-stalls-due-to-rtsp)

But still, it is waiting for 30 seconds before raising the warning.

OpenCV version: 4.4.0.x
Python version: 3.9.x

Can we decrease the wait time from 30 seconds to a lower number ?

Comment: Use av libary it can handle this way better

Comment: Thanks. But can we convert av image output to opencv mat ? I have developed the solution using opencv only.

Comment: Sure use frame.to_ndarray(format="bgr24")