# Basler bip2 640c camera pylon connection

Tags: basler

I want to use opencv to process images from Balser Bip2 640c camera using the pylon sdk. I have tried the sdk example to connect to the camera but I cannot find the camera. Is that a special sdk for these old cameras?

I have tried to print the available camera name but nothing work

```
from pypylon import pylon
tl_factory = pylon.TlFactory.GetInstance()
devices = tl_factory.EnumerateDevices()
for device in devices:
    print(device.GetFriendlyName())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pylon SDK is not the way to go with old BIP2 cameras. These are RSTP-based compressed stream IP cameras and there are several steps to access them:

- BIPFinder.exe software - you discover devices in your network, set proper IP number. Try to find it on [www.baslerweb.com](http://www.baslerweb.com) in Software Downloads section. Not sure however if it's still there.
- web interface - once camera is discovered via BIPFinder, then you open its interface in your browser. You configure it there, change settings, get preview ect.
- HTTP/CGI API - you can use it to programmatically set commands and get video stream from camera. Google for "Basler BIP2 API Description" pdf document. Version 3.x should work for BIP2.

On OpenCV's end, there are methods to directly connect to stream, given camera stream's url [(like here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891936/rtsp-stream-and-opencv-python). Just browse SO for more information under tag [opencv].

Hope it helps.